# Must declare the table variable "@temp"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I create a stored procedure in which I am using a dynamic query. The query will get data from my query and insert into my temp table and in last I select data from `@temp` table.

This is my stored procedure:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE uspSearchEmployee 
@Name varchar(50)= null,
@EmpNumber varchar(50)=null,
@Location Varchar(50)=null,
@position varchar(50)=null,
@partialmatch bit ,
@partialmatch2 bit,
@partialmatch3 bit 

AS
BEGIN
declare @wheresql varchar(max)


if (@Name is not null)
BEGIN
if(@partialmatch=1)
 set @wheresql=' where EmpName like ''%'+  @Name + ''''
else
  set @wheresql=' where EmpName = ' +@Name
END
IF(@Name is null AND @EmpNumber IS NOT NULL )
BEGIN
if(@partialmatch2=1)
 set @wheresql=' where EmployeeNum like ''%' + @EmpNumber + ''''
else
  set @wheresql=' where EmployeeNum = '+@EmpNumber
END 
IF(@Name is NOT null AND @EmpNumber IS NOT NULL )
BEGIN
if(@partialmatch2=1)
 set @wheresql=@wheresql+' AND EmployeeNum like ''%'+@EmpNumber +''''
else
  set @wheresql=@wheresql+' AND EmployeeNum ='+@EmpNumber
END 
--3rd case
IF(@Name is null AND @EmpNumber IS NULL AND @Location IS NOT NULL )
BEGIN
if(@partialmatch3=1)
 set @wheresql=' where Location like ''%' +@Location + ''''
else
  set @wheresql=' where Location = ' +@Location
END 
IF((@Name is NOT null OR @EmpNumber IS NOT NULL) AND @Location IS NOT NULL )
BEGIN
if(@partialmatch3=1)
 set @wheresql=@wheresql+ ' AND Location like ''%'+@EmpNumber + ''''
else
  set @wheresql=@wheresql+' AND Location ='+@EmpNumber
END 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #temp
 CREATE TABLE #temp          
(        
  EmpId int,
  EmpName varchar(40),
  Location varchar(50)null,
  City varchar(40)null,
  STPROV varchar(15)null,
  EmergencyPhone varchar(50)null,
  ZIPPOSTAL varchar(10) null,
  Home_Phone varchar(25)null,
  Country varchar(25) null,
  Department varchar(50) null,
  Position varchar(50) null,
  WorkCompCode varchar(50) null,
  Active bit null        
)  
set @wheresql=' INSERT INTO #temp
                SELECT  EmpId,EmpName,Location,City,STPROV,EmergencyPhone,ZIPPOSTAL,Home_Phone,Country,Department
                Position,WorkCompCode,Active 
                from employee ' + ISNULL(@wheresql, '')  
 PRINT  @wheresql  
  EXECUTE  sys.sp_executesql @wheresql
 Select * FROM  #temp


END
```

When I execute I get error message

> Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
>   Must declare the table variable "@temp".

What am I doing wrong in this query?

Regards

Comment: Variables are defined only within current scope. execute(@sql) creates new scope for executed sql.

Comment: You've completely changed the code in the question now, haven't you, because it no longer makes sense? There's no `@temp` table variable inside the stored procedure at all, and yet the surrounding text and error message still refer to it. If there's still a problem with the code, you need to edit the rest of the question. If there's *not* a problem with the code you're showing, please revert back to the broken code. Questions are meant to remain usable in years to come, and if the question no longer shows the error, it'll just confuse people. Upvotes and acceptance of answers is how to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use temporary tables -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.uspSearchEmployee

    @Name VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @EmpNumber VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Location VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @position VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @partialmatch BIT,
    @partialmatch2 BIT,
    @partialmatch3 BIT

AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    IF @Name IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF (@partialmatch = 1)
            SET @SQL = ' WHERE EmpName LIKE ''%' + @Name + ''''
        ELSE
            SET @SQL = ' WHERE EmpName = ' + @Name
    END

    IF @Name IS NULL AND @EmpNumber IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF (@partialmatch2 = 1)
            SET @SQL = ' WHERE EmployeeNum LIKE ''%' + @EmpNumber + ''''
        ELSE
            SET @SQL = ' WHERE EmployeeNum = ' + @EmpNumber

        IF (@partialmatch2 = 1)
            SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND EmployeeNum LIKE ''%' + @EmpNumber + ''''
        ELSE
            SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND EmployeeNum =' + @EmpNumber
    END

    IF @Name IS NULL AND @EmpNumber IS NULL AND @Location IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF (@partialmatch3 = 1)
            SET @SQL = ' WHERE Location LIKE ''%' + @Location + ''''
        ELSE
            SET @SQL = ' WHERE Location = ' + @Location
    END

    IF (@Name IS NOT NULL OR @EmpNumber IS NOT NULL) AND @Location IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF (@partialmatch3 = 1)
            SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND Location LIKE ''%' + @EmpNumber + ''''
        ELSE
            SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND Location =' + @EmpNumber
    END

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #temp

    CREATE TABLE #temp 
    (
        EmpId INT,
        EmpName VARCHAR(40),
        Location VARCHAR(50) NULL,
        City VARCHAR(40) NULL,
        STPROV VARCHAR(15) NULL,
        EmergencyPhone VARCHAR(50) NULL,
        ZIPPOSTAL VARCHAR(10) NULL,
        Home_Phone VARCHAR(25) NULL,
        Country VARCHAR(25) NULL,
        Department VARCHAR(50) NULL,
        Position VARCHAR(50) NULL,
        WorkCompCode VARCHAR(50) NULL,
        Active BIT NULL
    )

    SET @SQL = '
    INSERT INTO #temp
    SELECT EmpId,EmpName,Location,City,STPROV,EmergencyPhone,ZIPPOSTAL,Home_Phone,Country,Department,Position,WorkCompCode,Active 
    FROM dbo.employee ' + ISNULL(@SQL, '')

    PRINT @SQL
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

    SELECT * FROM #temp

END
```

Comment: @Davart its given error `Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'. `

Comment: How to use here if (@Name is not null)

Comment: `IF @Name IS NULL` equal to `ISNULL(@SQL, '')`

Comment: can you please take a look the question i have updated